# Creating quip app - not logged in to quip

Tags: quip, liveapps

I am following the instructions on the website to create the tutorial quip app. When I try running "create-quip-app my-app" I get an error that says

Error: Not logged in to quip.com

Refusing to create an app since we can't contact Quip servers.

How do I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Should be resolved in the new version, v0.1.1 - run `npm i -g create-quip-app@latest` and try again!

Comment: Hi Jesse, welcome to SFSE! Sounds like you're a member of the Quip product team - if that's the case, could you [edit] to be explicit about your role so that the community understands where you're coming from, and share any references like a WI number folks can track? Thanks!